# AWS Firehose changes data encoding

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have this weird problem that I don't understand, namely that it seems firehose is changing the encoding of the data that I send to the stream after I put the record.

I see this because when I publish the data with the put_record() API call, the value for the encoded json string that I put is this:

```
eyJMb2NrYm.....=
```

but then I have a transformation lambda and when I read in the data that I just put, the encoding string is like this:

```
ZXlKTWIyTnJZ....==
```

(NOTE: I have truncated the middle of the encoded string for brevity sake)

This is a problem because when I try to decode the string I get, it doesn't decode to anything, just the same string.
Am I doing something wrong? I get not error on the put command, which tells me the input is correct, but how come when I try and read it back, the value is not what I expect? Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem. On the Firehose "put_record" API Call, the input is not an encoded base64, it is just supposed to be a string. On the backend they do the encoding so when it shows up on retrieving the record, it is encoded.

This was not clear to me from the docs as I read it here: [boto3 put_record](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/firehose.html#Firehose.Client.put_record)

So all I did was change my input to "json.dumps(my_dict)" to the API Call and on the other end I got the expected base64 encoded string